# How Create new column in Pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Quick silly question -  I am sure this was asked before, but couldn't file detail. I have a dataframe  df_students as below -

```
Student ID, Subjects ,  MArks_Received, Marks
222         English     3               90
222         Maths       3               80
222         Science     3               70
223         English     2               90
223         Maths       2               80
224         Maths       2               80
```

I am looking for below output based on Subjects and Received conditions, if no's of rows don't match for each student, will have to add extra Colum ( PENDING) or Received.

```
Student ID, Subjects ,  Expected_Rows, Marks, State
222         English     3               90    Received  
222         Maths       3               80    Received
222         Science     3               70    Received
223         English     2               90    Received
223         Maths       2               80    Received
224         Maths       2               80    PENDING
```

As I have Expected_Rows 2 for "224" , but received only 1 , I should mark this as "Pending".

I am able to aggregate sum of marks as below, but cant figure out how to add State. Any help is highlight appreciated.

## Aggregate data frame

```
df_aggregate = df_students.groupby(['Student ', 'Marks'])['Marks'].agg(sum).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches, please see below if this helps:

Add a new column `'count'` and then `'State'` basis that:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Student ID')['Student ID'].transform('count')
df['State'] = np.where(df['Count'] != df['MArks_Received'], 'PENDING','Received')
```

If you don't want to add a new column then use the following:

```
df['State'] = np.where(df.groupby('Student ID')['Student ID'].transform('count') != df['MArks_Received'], 'PENDING','Received')
```

It consider the rows where the count of `'Student ID'` doesn't match with `'Expected Rows'`.

Comment: Thanks Manoj for quick help - will give it a go